# Anyone hear when NLTK 3.0 will be out?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

The website, http://www.nltk.org, says mid 2011 in a very vague manner.  I would like to start using NLTK however I have done a fair amount of work with Python 3.x and I don't want to have to go backwards in Python version just to use it.  Just doing an effort analysis, if the wait is long enough I might bite the bullet and revert my Python.

Comment: Maybe people know more here: http://groups.google.com/group/nltk-users

Comment: Porting from Python 3 to Python 2 is not that much work as long as you can avoid Python 2.5. There is a fair bit of forward compatibility in 2.6 and 2.7. The bytes/string/unicode issue is the only real tricky one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a Python 3 branch:

https://github.com/nltk/nltk/tree/nltk-py3k

It's a transformation of the trunk and gets updated every so often to keep up with changes.  You can check it out directly from git (instead of using the NLTK installation) and give it a shot.

```
git clone git://github.com/nltk/nltk.git nltk --branch nltk-py3k
```

I haven't used it personally, but I assume it works.

Comment: I'll check it out when I can and report back.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Ok I have got installed fine on my windows machine.  Everything appears to look good, but there are many dependencies and like I said I am new to it, so it will be a good learning experience.  Thanks for the heads up on the nltk3 branch.  I tend to like binaries when I don't see foresee the need to alter the code.

Comment: And now this branch seems to be gone. :(

Comment: I think this might be the closest thing we have now https://github.com/kmike/nltk.  From what I understand, it is still a work in progress though.

Comment: The NLTK master branch now is being actively developed to support both Python 2 and 3: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/tree/master

Comment: NLTK 3.0 will be the first release with support for python 3, as Steve mentioned above development is now being done in the master branch and the nltk-py3k branch no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "2and3" branch in the main nltk repo - see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/tree/2and3

It appears to be getting updated regularly, although I haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the alpha release: https://github.com/nltk/nltk3-alpha

Alternative NLP: TextBlob is fully Python 3. https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob

Tutorial: http://www.stevenloria.com/how-to-build-a-text-classification-system-with-python-and-textblob/

Answer (score 1):

For those who got here wondering when will nltk support python3:

Good news, the NLTK 3.0 series (currently on alpha and in development since Jan 2013) now support Python 2.6, 2.7 and Python 3 (http://www.nltk.org/nltk3-alpha/), We'll probably see a stable release soon :)

And the book is also being updated for python3, available at: http://www.nltk.org/book3/

Answer (score 0):

So, the official release was in September 2014, just to add closure to the question