# Greek encoding in PYTHON

Tags: python, encoding

i'm trying to store a string  and after tokenize it with nltk in python.But i cant understand why after tokenizing it ( it creates a list ) i cant see the strings in list..
Can anyone help me plz?

Here is the code:

```
#a="Γεια σου"
#b=nltk.word_tokenize(a)
#b
['\xc3\xe5\xe9\xe1', '\xf3\xef\xf5']
```

I just want to be able to see the content of the list regularly..

Thx in advance

Answer (score 6):

You are using Python 2, where unprefixed quotes denote a *byte* as opposed to a *character* string (if you're not sure about the difference, [read this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)). Either switch to Python 3, where this has been fixed, or prefix all character strings with `u` and print the strings (as opposed to showing their `repr`, which differs in Python 2.x):

```
>>> import nltk
>>> a = u'Γεια σου'
>>> b = nltk.word_tokenize(a)
>>> print(u'\n'.join(b))
Γεια
σου
```

Comment: my problem is not the "print" solution...i just wanted to be able to see the contents of b so i can later process them with language functions like pos-tag and stemming.Is this possible that way?

Comment: @GreekBurner Well, what you're seeing *are* the contents of `b`, just not in a representation you expect. You can switch to Python 3, where the default representation of `'Γεια σου'` is `Γεια σου`.

Comment: Thx but the nltk package i use, supports only Python 2.. :(
Anyway thx

Comment: @GreekBurner There [seems to be a Python3  branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501271/anyone-hear-when-nltk-3-0-will-be-out), but just using `print` (and accepting that Python 2's representation is weird) is probably indeed the easier route.

Comment: @phihag: Suggesting to switch Python versions only because OP doesn't know the difference between `repr()` and what `print` produces is insane. Note: the issue is not Unicode string literals vs. bytestring literals (the `repr()` of Unicode string is also unreadable). `>>> print "\n".join("Γεια σου".split())` produces the desired output despite everything being bytes. Though for working with text Unicode strings should be used whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the strings. The characters are represented by escape sequences because of your terminal encoding settings. Configure your terminal to accept input, and present output, in UTF-8.

Comment: And how can i configure them?( i use the GUI python shell )
If i work like this will i be able to use stemmers and pos-taggers on those lists are created??

Comment: I don't use the GUI shell. Consult the documentation.

Comment: No, the bytes (not characters) are not represented by escape sequences because of the terminal encoding; it's just their `repr`esentation. Observe `u'ä'` vs `print(u'ä')` vs `print(repr(u'ä'))` in a properly-configured terminal.

Comment: @phihag You're making a non-existent distinction, as python does not have a character type.

Comment: @Marcin But Python has a character *string* type, and the question doesn't use it at all. Observe `isinstance("Γεια σου", bytes)`

Comment: @phihag It has a unicode type. You can call it what you like, but this is a purely linguistic dispute.

Comment: In regards to this question, the distinction is essential, as the code would otherwise only work if source file and terminal encoding match.

Comment: @Marcin Create a file with the OP's encoding (ISO-8859-7) with the contents (`# coding=iso-8859-7  <newline> print("Γεια σου")`) and execute it in your UTF-8 terminal.

Comment: @phihag This does not demonstrate your point. It demonstrates that python can cope with two different encodings, not that "the code would otherwise only work if source file and terminal encoding match".

Comment: @Marcin No offense, but have you actually run that code in a UTF-8 terminal? It outputs `���� ���`, which I wouldn't describe as a *demonstration that python can cope with two different encodings*.