# How to use Python 2 packages in Python 3 project?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How to use python 2 packages in python 3 project?

I have a Python 3 project, but I need some packages which are written in Python 2.

**I do not want to rewrite these python-2 packages, so forking / 2to3 is not an option.**

Comment: Your linked dynatree is about 4 years old (time since last commit). Combining the above 2 comments: clone/fork it to your local disk, run 2to3 and install it manually. As it is by now near abandonware, it's unlikely it will be made Python 3 compatible for you.

Comment: @fjarri Experiences are mixed. If the code uses a lot of Python 2 constructs or is just hard to understand, it might be a major undertaking. Here is one recent blog which says "not so onerous" http://ilovesymposia.com/2015/03/08/experiences-porting-a-medium-sized-library-from-python-2-to-3/ but there are others with differing opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Any module you import in py3 codebase needs to be py3 compatible. If you can't make the upstream project do it for you, you'll have to do it yourself. As mentioned in the comments, `2to3` utility should help you with that.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of the previous questions concern using Python 2 modules in Python 3 projects. Here's the [most complete explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14077658/911945). It also works the other way around and suggests the following alternatives:

1. Using the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module for requests and getting the response through the CLI. So far the most straightforward way to make cross-references.
   [`python-fire`](https://github.com/google/python-fire) can quickly add a CLI to a Python 3 library. You'll have a reasonable API to call from the Python 2 project.
2. [`3to2`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/3to2). This utility converts Python 3 code to Python 2. It remains unclear how it handles complex Python 3 projects with dependencies and Python 3-only features.
3. [`six`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) and [`__future__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html). It seems both of these modules are intended for writing the code compatible with Python 2-3, not for using Python 3 libraries in Python 2 projects.