# Standardize the Addresses using Python Library address

Tags: python

I am trying to standardize the addresses by separating the address 1 and address 2 from the given address for all countries.
Example: given address: 123 West Mifflin Street, Madison, WI, 53703
So, I am planning to use the "address" library
I installed the address library by using `pip install address` in Anaconda.
it was installed successfully.
In Jupiter notebook, I typed the below code and tried to run it

```
from address import AddressParser, Address

ap = AddressParser()

address = ap.parse_address('123 West Mifflin Street, Madison, WI, 53703')
```

I am getting the below error:

```
File "C:\Users\vatti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-26-c32728fd4cb5>", line 1, in <module>
    from address import AddressParser, Address

  File "C:\Users\vatti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\address\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .address import Address, AddressParser

  File "C:\Users\vatti\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\address\address.py", line 185
    print "Unmatched token: ", token
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Unmatched token: ", token)?
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Python 2 packages in Python 3 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885975/how-to-use-python-2-packages-in-python-3-project)

Comment: [`address`](https://pypi.org/project/address/) is designed for Python 2 only; it was never updated. You're using Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are running Python 2.X code with a Python 3.x interpreter.  The line at the bottom of the error stacktrace you provide is:

```
print "Unmatched token: ", token
```

This code is valid in Python 2.X, but is a syntax error in Python 3.X.  Since it appears that the code in question is in the module `address` rather than your code, you need to either drop down to Python 2.X yourself, or upgrade that module to a version that supports python 3.X.  Since `pip` usually installs the latest version of a package, my guess is that the author of that package hasn't upgraded it to support Python 3.X.  It's possible that there's Python 3.X version under a different name.

UPDATE: I was curious if this problem was isolated to Anaconda.  I use the standard vanilla Python distribution.  I just tried installing the package and running your code.  I get the same thing.

Comment: cryptofool, thanks...Can anyone help me what is the library name that is compatible to Python 3.X and works for all the countries. I tried pyap library but it is not working for AT(Austria).

Comment: The library was [released in January of 2013](https://pypi.org/project/address/#files) and never had a second release.  My guess is that there is no newer version of this library.  The library consists of just two Python files and three CSV files.  You might be able to fix the library yourself, and maybe just include it in your own codebase.

Comment: I can't modify it. I am very new to python. I need someone's help.

Comment: thank you very much. I am looking at different library to resolve this issue.